# Java ME Emulator não inicia

Tags: java, emulador, java-me, j2me

Estou tentando iniciar o emulador Java para dispositivos móveis, porém ao inicia-lo diretamente de seu executável, ele apresenta uma tela preta. Em seguida, na bandeja do sistema, aparece o ícone do device-manager que até me permite clicar sobre ele e acessar suas opções até que ele, do nada, desaparece. A tela preta do emulador permanece por mais alguns instantes e se fecha sozinha também.Isso acontece com todas as versões acima da 3.4

No NetBeans, não consigo adicionar esta plataforma JAVA ME, pois o NetBeans não detecta o emulador, o que me leva a crer que o problema esteja no device-manager.

Já tentei modificar o arquivo .properties dentro da pasta do emulador, já configurei o acesso às portas do firewall, realizei vários outros procedimentos, incluindo instalar versões diferentes do JDK (uso sistema Windows 10 x64 e troquei o JDk x64 por x86, mesmo assim nenhum resultado positivo).

Alguém conhece alguma forma de fazer com que o emulador funcione?